# Bundle items fail after having previously worked

Tags: textmate, textmate2

Depending on the bundle item the exact error for a failing Textmate2 bundle can change, but his is the one I was getting for "Comment Line / Selection" on a previously pristine Textmate2

`Comment Line / Selection:16:in 'require': no such file to load -- /lib/escape (LoadError)
    from Comment Line / Selection:16`

How do I fix my bundles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try this:

```
Delete this file: ~/Library/Caches/com.macromates.TextMate/BundlesIndex.plist

Then relaunch TextMate.

This is a problem with the cache not properly updating when bundles 
are changed on disk (as they would have been recently, as a lot of 
bundles got updated) — so far though I only know it happens, not why it happens…'
```

Source: Textmate Email List

Then, if that doesn't work, try this:

```
Textmate -> Preferences -> Bundles and uninstall and reinstall "Bundle Support"
then quit and relaunch Textmate.
```